# changing limit with integral sign

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question: For $z$ not in the real interval $[0,1]$, let $f(z)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^{2}dt}{t-z}$. Show that $f$ is differentiable.

I got $\lim_{z\rightarrow w}\,\,\int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^2}{(t-z)(t-w)}\,\,\,\,$ . Now I know that we can change the limit with integral if the integrand uniformly convergent, but I couldn't show that. Any help would be great.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary. An easier approach might be something like Cauchy's integral formula or something. I'm not sure if that will work. If you really want to do it this way, Dominated Converge theorem is the way to go.

Comment: I just solved, thanks.

Comment: If you want you can post your solution as an answer and we will check to make sure it's correct.

Comment: Morera's theorem could also be used to show $f$ is holomorphic in that region.

Comment: I realized that it is a cauchy type integral so the same argument in the proof of the cauchy integral formula's proof works.